# Django runserver bound to 0.0.0.0, how can I get which IP took the request?

Tags: python, django, manage.py

I'm running a temporary Django app on a host that has lots of IP addresses. When using `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000`, how can the code see which of the many IP addresses of the machine was the one actually hit by the request, if this is even possible?

Or to put it another way:

My host has IP addresses `10.0.0.1` and `10.0.0.2`. When runserver is listening on `0.0.0.0`, how can my application know whether the user hit `http://10.0.0.1/app/path/etc` or `http://10.0.0.2/app/path/etc`?

I understand that if I was doing it with Apache I could use the Apache environment variables like `SERVER_ADDR`, but I'm not using Apache.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

More information:

I'm testing a load balancer using a small Django app. This app is listening on a number of different IPs and I need to know which IP address is hit for a request coming through the load balancer, so I can ensure it is balancing properly.

I cannot use `request.get_host()` or the `request.META` options, as they return what the user typed to hit the load balancer.

For example: the user hits `http://10.10.10.10/foo` and that will forward the request to either `http://10.0.0.1/foo` or `http://10.0.0.2/foo` - but `request.get_host()` will return `10.10.10.10`, not the actual IPs the server is listening on.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Why not just binding it to a specific ip? `python manage.py runserver 10.0.0.1(2):5000`

Comment: I think what @Ben is trying to say is how does the server detect which IP was hit with a request?

Comment: Yes @GamesBrainiac, that's exactly what I mean :)

Comment: I know but, why bother, django's server is not intended to production. I was just suggesting, it's a very valid question anyways :)

Answer (score 5):

```
request.get_host()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host

but be aware this can be cheated so don't relay your security on it.

If users are seeing your machine under same address I am not sure if this is possible via runserver (it is supposed to be simple development tool).

Maybe you could use nginx?
Or if this is only for testing do something like:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do manage.py runserver 10.0.0.$i:5000; done
```

and then sys.args[2] is your address

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer - I've edited my answer to include more information.

Comment: ok i see, than i don't know how to do it, added some suggestions to my answer thou

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to ensure the load balancer is working correctly, I suppose it's not an absolute requirement to do this in the application code. You can use a network packet analyzer that can listen on a specific interface (say, `tcpdump -i <interface>`) and look at the output.